# Did Korach get Tzaraat?

Tags: tzaraas-negaim, parshat-korach

When Korach was rebelling against Moshe Rabbeinu, was he in fact stricken with Tzaraat? If he was stricken, then couldn't that serve as an indication that he was in the wrong?

Korach rebelled not too far away from the episode of Miriam receiving Tzaraat.

A rebellion from Korach, no matter how small or big, should have incurred Tzaraat. At the very first instance of negative speech, Korach should've been excommunicated.

Additionally, Moshe Rabbeinu **himself** felt there was a chance to save Korach and the 250 men, by pushing off the challenge to the succeeding day, giving the rebels time to think about what they're getting themselves into. Moshe Rabbeinu **personally** went over to Dasan and Aviram to make Shalom, exemplifying that there was ***SOMETHING SALVAGEABLE***! Moshe Rabbeinu saw a sliver of hope. He was willing, just if only they were willing as well.

Wouldn't Tzaraat have helped saved these men from Gehennom? Surely Hashem would rather a person do Teshuva than to punish someone. The arrogance and jealousy perhaps may have been exterminated by performing the rites of the Metzorah, bringing 2 birds, shaving the entire body, etc.

Comment: Could you imagine if I came up to you and asked you "When Kayin killed Hevel, was he in fact stricken with the flu?"? You would assume I'm crazy. Flu _man d'char sh'meh_, as they say: where did I pull flu out of?

Comment: Apparently the rebellion was even more than *just* lashan hara. As a result the punishment was much more. Miriam got tzaraas **because** she was able to learn the lesson. An analogy might be someone who brings a chatas rather than getting the actual punishment of kares

Comment: The content of your comment to me should be in the question post instead. The post as is reads like someone posted it without thinking. Put some logic in it and maybe you'll get more answererers. Plus, if someone knows why you think Korach should've gotten _tzaraas_, he can address that point and explain why the reason is irrelevant to Korach (as indeed sabbahillel did in a comment. He wouldn't have done that had you not explained). Comments are ephemeral by design and are liable to be deleted at any time: put all relevant info in the question post itself. There's plenty of room there.

Comment: Your question isn't just a clever comparison. It's in a Midrash that appears in several places. For instance, in Midrash Tanchuma P' Korach 10: אמר רב כל המחזיק במחלוקת עובר בלאו, הוא שנאמר ולא יהיה כקרח וכעדתו, רב אסי אמר ראוי הוא להצטרע כתיב הכא כאשר דבר ה' ביד משה לו, וכתיב התם )שמות ב( ויאמר ה' לו עוד הבא נא ידך וגו. Anyone who argues against Moshe and makes machlokes - _like Korach_ - gets tzora'as. (See also the Rambam, Sefer Hamitzvos, Shoresh 8, who brings that Midrash as the reason that the verse is not one of the Taryag Mitzvos.)